# Program prints result I want except in one place I get the memory address instead of the value of the address.

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

Basically the  exercise says "Create a function which takes as an argument an array and its size and returns a new array with contains the three biggest values of the array given as the argument." So I thought that I will take the array and sort it in the function and then give the 3 highest values to a new array and return it. That's my code.

```
int *function(int *A, int k){
    int B[3],i,j,temp;

    //Sorting
    for(i=k-1;i>0;i--){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(A[j-1] > A[j])
            {
                temp = A[j-1];
                A[j-1] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < 3){
        B[i]= A[k-1];
        i++;
        k--;
    }
    return B;   
} 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   int A[5] = {1,8,7,4,6};
    int size = 5;
    int *func,i;

    func = function(A,size);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%d ",func[i]); 
    return 0;
}
```

As a result I should get 8 7 6 but I'm getting 8 -1073743756 6. I can't find the mistake. I also get a warning when I want to return B. It says "Function return address of local variable." Maybe this has something to do with this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'lifetime' of the variable B is for the duration of the function in which it is declared.  When it is out of scope it no longer exists, and its memory may be reused for other purposes.  You should regard all compiler warnings as errors - they are usually semantic errors (as opposed to syntax errors); that is to say, the compiler understands the code, but it is unlikely that it is what you intended, or may have unintended or undefined behaviour.

In this case the compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is.  What you need to be asking perhaps is how best to resolve the error.

The normal pattern to use when a caller requires an array to be filled by a function is for the caller to provide the array to the function.  Because arrays 'decay' to pointers when passed to a function, it is normal to also pass the length, and this is useful to avoid buffer overrun.  You could have the function "know" that the buffer length is always 3 in your case, but it is less maintainable and less safe.

Typically such a function returns a pointer to the caller's buffer, or NULL on failure, so it can be used for error checking or for use as the argument to another function.

Example:

```
int* fn( int* caller_buffer, int caller_buffer_length )
{
    int i ;
    for( i = 0; i < caller_buffer_length; i++ )
    {
        caller_buffer[i] = ... ;
    }
}
```

then

```
int my_buffer[3] = {0} ;
int my_buffer_length = sizeof(my_buffer) / sizeof(*my_buffer) ;
int* error_check = 0 ;

...

error_check = fn( my_buffer, my_buffer_length ) ;
if( error_check != 0 )
{
    ...
}
```

It is possible to resolve the problem by either allocating B statically, globally, or dynamically.  All these solutions I would class as "quick-and-dirty".  They may resolve this particular problem, but are not a general pattern that scales well to more complex and larger applications.

Dynamic memory allocation locally within `function()` begs the question of who is then responsible to freeing the memory allocated?

Local static allocation works, but if you call the function a second time the previous data will be lost, which may not always be acceptable.  It is also not reentarnt, causing potential problems in a multi-threaded application, or recursive algorithms.

Global data is statically allocated but as the additional problem of being globally visible, so no longer under the sole control of the one function.

Answer (score 3):

After the function returns, automatic storage objects (such as `int B[3]`) are destroyed so referring to them is illegal. In practice you will get unexpected values because of various stuff written to the stack:

You can:

- Give B static storage
- Use `malloc` (and later `free`)
- Use a different approach altogether, such as making the caller responsible for passing `B`

Comment: So I made some changes. I made int *B and then B = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int)) and the program works and the warning also isn't there anymore. But what is the difference between writing B[3] and using malloc to write the array B? Don't we use malloc when we don't know from the beginning the size of an array? In this example I know from the beginning that array B will be of size 3.

Comment: These suggestions are not in order of advisability; I would turn the list upside down.

Answer (score 1):

B is a local variable, and goes away when function exits.

Declare B outside function, and pass it by pointer to function.

Answer (score 1):

The `B[]` array only *lives* when `function()` is running, (it is *local*). After return it is un-refferenced.

If your task text is precisely quoted it seems like you'll have to dig into malloc. And then I'll say now:

- Do not cast malloc
- free() when done

Reason for using malloc, following *the text*:

1. *"Return a **new** array"*
2. *"Takes only an array and counter"*, not a third parameter or re-use of *A*.

And do not fall for the temptation to use an global array ;), tho you are perhaps allowed to use static? -*(Edit: @Clifford has good points on why-not)*

Best of luck!

---

**Edit:**
Also: you do not *"get the memory address instead of value"*.

When `function()` is called it is given an address on where to return. Second the memory for the *local* variables, in that function, are reserved and their designations given the address. Ie. something like:

```
/* assuming 4 byte int */
[ 0xA4 ... 0xAF ] <-- int B[3]  -- 3 * 4 = 12 bytes
[ 0xB0 ... 0xB4 ] <-- int i     -- 4 bytes
[ 0xB5 ... 0xB9 ] <-- int j     -- 4 bytes
[ 0xBA ... 0xBE ] <-- int temp  -- 4 bytes
```

When the function returns these areas are freed. As there is no use to use power to erase the data it stays there, but can at any moment be overwritten when another operation uses the area.

I.e. from your code that could be `printf()` or it could be something entirely different. Point being that it is not *reserved* and can be used to *"what ever"*. (Not making pancakes, but I guess you get that).

So, when you print your values of `func` and get 2 correct and one wrong this means the two first has not yet been overwritten, and the last has been overwritten by another call. It could even be in use.

---

The last value is not an address, but another value interpreted as integer. It does not have to be an int either. If another function wrote a short int or a char to that area (most probably 4 bytes), what you do is read 4 bytes and interpret the bits in to an int.

Say:

```
B[2] == 6 (on a 4 bytes, int 32, system)

Address: 0xAC 0xAD 0xAE 0xAF       As bit sequence
Value  :    6    0    0    0  ==> [0000 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000]
```

*Returning to main*, `fun[2] -> [0xC 0xD 0xE 0xF]`

Somewhere else a function defines a `char` (1 byte) and get the now free address `0xD`
It writes the value 123 to that address.

Now we have:

```
fun[2]:

Address: 0xAC 0xAD 0xAE 0xAF       As bit sequence
Value  :    6  123    0    0  ==> [0000 0110 0111 1011 0000 0000]
```

Or if we translate that on an little-endian system, (like mine), to an integer we get

```
          +--------- Least significant byte
          |
Address: 0xAC 0xAD 0xAE 0xAF
Value  :    6  123    0    0  ( == 0x06 0x7B 0x00 0x00 )

Sort to "human Anglo left right order"
0 0 123 6 => 0x00007B06 == 31494 (int, "normal human number"), and the number
                                       you print when doing the for() loop in 
                                       main.
```

---

It could also as well be that the bytes in question are used like

```
                   +----- bytes of fun[2]
                   |
          _________+_________
         [                   ]
char foo 0xAC                |
int  bar       0xAD 0xAE 0xAF  0xB0
               [____+______________]
                    |
                    +---- bytes of bar
```

---

*The fact that number 1 and 2 are correct is neither any guarantee that the bytes has not been changed. The same value can have been written to the location. 0 can have been written to byte 2 of the int etc.*

Hoover to show:

> *As a semi note, only to confuse further, it *could* be an address, but then the integer representation of that address. In fact that is not that unlikely ... It could ie be return address for some action, that you interpret as an int.*

Hope you get at least 1% out of this. I'm active learning myself and explaining is often learning :)